# convert object into array and scroll it all value

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

How do I convert an **object** to an **array** and each scroll it all?

this is my **object**

```js
let obj = {
    each_hour: "20000",
    edit_photo: { yes: "20000", no: "0" },
    photo_type: { Personal: "1000", sport: "2100", Industrial: "1200", Commercial: "2300", Fashion: "1300", mode: { "name": "farhad" } },
    photograph_gender: { male: "0", female: "20000" }
}
```

**Required output:**

```json
each_hour
20000
edit_photo
yes
20000
no
0
photo_type
Personal
1000
sport
2100
Industrial
1200
...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a recursive function to loop through your object. If an array is passed into your function, you can map each value in the array to the return value of calling your function again on that individual element. If an object is passed through, you can obtain its entries by calling `Object.entries()` on your object, which will then execute the previously mentioned array mapping. Otherwise, if it's not an array or an object, you can return the value:

```js
function traverseObject(val) {
  if(Array.isArray(val)) {
    return val.flatMap(elem => traverseObject(elem));
  } else if(Object(val) === val) {
    return traverseObject(Object.entries(val));
  }
  return val;
}

const obj = { each_hour: "20000", edit_photo: { yes: "20000", no: "0" }, photo_type: { Personal: "1000", sport: "2100", Industrial: "1200", Commercial: "2300", Fashion: "1300", mode: { "name": "farhad" } }, photograph_gender: { male: "0", female: "20000" } }
traverseObject(obj).forEach(e => console.log(e));
```

You could also use the [replacer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify#the_replacer_parameter) function of JSON.stringify, as that will be called on every key/value pair in your object, but it's a little bit of a hack:

```js
function traverseObject(obj) {
  const res = [];
  JSON.stringify(obj, (key, val) => (key !== "" && res.push(key, ...(Object(val) === val ? [] : [val])), val));
  return res;
}
// works with arrays -\/
const obj = { foo: [4, 5, 6], each_hour: "20000", edit_photo: { yes: "20000", no: "0" }, photo_type: { Personal: "1000", sport: "2100", Industrial: "1200", Commercial: "2300", Fashion: "1300", mode: { "name": "farhad" } }, photograph_gender: { male: "0", female: "20000" } }
traverseObject(obj).forEach(e => console.log(e));
```

Answer (score 3):

As the data stands currently in the object, you can try using `JSON.stringify()`, `replace()` and `split()` like the following way:

```js
let obj = {
    each_hour: "20000",
    edit_photo: { yes: "20000", no: "0" },
    photo_type: { Personal: "1000", sport: "2100", Industrial: "1200", Commercial: "2300", Fashion: "1300", mode: { "name": "farhad" } },
    photograph_gender: { male: "0", female: "20000" }
}
 var res = JSON.stringify(obj).replace(/["{}]/g,'').split(/[:,]/);
 console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 0):

More old school (imperative coding style) approach with recursion if interested :-

Basically maintaining an `output` array to which we push the `key` and `value` obtained from `Object.entries`. If the `value` is an object, we recurse and if not we simply push to our `output` array.

Note - This is specific to your use case and not very generalized.

```js
let obj = {
    each_hour: "20000",
    edit_photo: { yes: "20000", no: "0" },
    photo_type: { Personal: "1000", sport: "2100", Industrial: "1200", Commercial: "2300", Fashion: "1300", mode: { "name": "farhad" } },
    photograph_gender: { male: "0", female: "20000" }
}


function objToArray(obj){

  const output = [];

  function processing(obj){
  for (const [key,value] of Object.entries(obj)){
    if(typeof value === 'object' ){
       output.push(key);
       processing(value);
    }
    else{
    output.push(key,value);
    }
  }
  }
  
  processing(obj);
  return output;
}

const result = objToArray(obj);
console.log(result);
```